# Undefined class constant 'API_VERSION_2_5_BC'

Tags: php, validation, symfony, composer-php

After creating a new 2.3 project then adding a set of dependencies to `composer.json`, the following error occurs when the `cache:clear` command is run at the end of `composer update`:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'API_VERSION_2_5_BC' in
>   ...\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\FrameworkExtension.php
>   on line 758

The dependencies added were taken from a fully functional existing project built on Symfony 2.5.  The objective is to experiment with adding Symfony CMF to the project, mostly to see if it adds needed functionality.

A search on `API_VERSION_2_5_BC` shows it is related to validation.  Is there a workaround, or should I abandon this effort?

#### composer.json (in part)

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jquery/jquery",
            "version": "1.11.1",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js",
                "type": "file"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "liip/functional-test-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "1.0.@dev",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.0.*",
    "jquery/jquery":  "1.11.*",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.0",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~3.0"
},
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you generate a 2.3 project?

Comment: @Stony As stated above, I was hoping to try adding the CMF to the existing project.  I was unable to simply add it to the project when its `composer.json` required Symfony `~2.4` due to insufficiently stable dependencies.